# Swift 2: Immutable value X is never used consider replacing with '_'

Tags: swift2

In several cases of my old code I am getting the warning:

> Immutable value X is never used consider replacing with '_'

For instance this often occurs if I am checking an enum which has an associated object (but I don't use the object in this case) - or if I am using the 'If let' construct to check if an object is nil or not.

It doesn't bother me that much to go through these warnings and make the changes, but I wondered if anyone knew why this is recommended - why bother warning us about this?  Would it affect performance in any way?

Comment: This is just Xcode being preemptive.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

These changes are recommended because if you don't use these variables at all you should consider replacing it with '_'. So you (and other people) can later understand your intention more quickly.

In terms of performance it would probably be just a minor improvement which you can't notice at all. The same situation applies during compilation and optimization of your code.

Comment: Hi Qbyte, do you have any doc from apple for this case?

Comment: @lee Unfortunately not, but I'm pretty sure that the first case is true since the compiler suggests it. In case of performance I could imagine that the result is optimized away even though you leave the variable.

Answer (score 25):

**Immutable value X is never used consider replacing with '_'**

this warning coming because you are not using your variable after declaring it. just ignore the warning and keep writing your code and use your object , **it will vanished .**

Swift 2 is very sensitive language it will give you warning on every step .

i am explaining a simple demo of warning of any object here :- 
1 .**Immutable value X is never used consider replacing with '_'**
it will come when you will do not use of object and declare it only.
Ex:-

```
var nameImg:String = "";
```

2.**variable 'nameImg'was written to,but never read.**
it will come when you will assign your object any value but you are still not using it in any other object .
Ex-

```
  var nameImg:String = "";
                    if(action==1){
                        nameImg  = "navTab";
                    }
                    else{
                        nameImg  = "back";
                    }
```

3. **No Warnings** will come if you are assigning any value to your object and using it in another object too ;).

Ex-

```
 var nameImg:String = "";
                    if(action==1){
                        nameImg  = "navTab";
                    }
                    else{
                        nameImg  = "back";
                    }


                    //back & menu btn
                    let btnBack = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom);
                    btnBack.setImage(UIImage(named:nameImg), forState: UIControlState.Normal);
                    btnBack.sizeToFit();
```

Comment: why we use declare object in another object???if we dont want to use the its give warning why?is this bug of sift language?? i need only this one line  let stingname : String = objectfile.name
but its give me warning why??if i am using in print statement then its not give any warning.....why??

Comment: let stingname : String = objectfile.name that means swift is helping you with warning or you can say as alert  that its still not use any where in our project so please you have to use it.:) when you print (print("str\(stingname)"))  it was used by you . and warning vanished.. so for ios development its very nice for us that swift is helping in  everycase by yellow warnings..just we have to read them seriously and love their  useful meanings. Best Regards

Comment: no,its saying what ever object you are creating in swift you should use them , rest those object are useless..;)

Answer (score 3):

It is because your value was never used after declaring it, I had the exact same problem not too long ago.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)


    let row = indexPath.row <-----
```

I found that just printing it after made the error go away.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)


    let row = indexPath.row <---
    print(row) <---
```

Comment: This solution is good if you only are declaring a value for storing a strong reference to something that needs to live the life of the function call. I only ever do this in tests but sometimes this is just what I need. If something has side effects you want to trigger but does not have discardable results for return type, than assigning to _ is better.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should work warning free in day-to-day work. The obvious reason is that you are going to miss the *real* and important warnings if your code produces hundreds of not so important warnings.

The case you are describing is best solved in this way: instead of using `if let myObject = myObject` you better use:

```
if myObject != nil
```

In this way it is clear what you *want* to do.

Answer (score -1):

This warning comes up because Xcode wants you to change the variable. Xcode wants the variable has not been used. Hope this helps. Once you use it the error goes away. I have repeatedly have tried this as well as researched it and it in fact goes away every time.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the answer because it will resolve someone else problem ASAP